# Select query using JSON_OBJECT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('date',date,'hourly_data',CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('data',data)),']')) as datalist
FROM time_evaluate
WHERE in_time >= '2018-10-01 00:00:00' AND in_time <= '2018-10-01 23:59:00';
```

I'm trying to get data display on screen or in console. But it is not displaying full data on the screen.

Comment: what is your json object size

Comment: @Shadiqur object size : 1440